# yii2 remove backend/web and frontend/web from url

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to change site url from http://localhost/yiiwebsite/backend/web/index.php url to http://localhost/yiiwebsite/admin and http://localhost/yiiwebsite/frontend/web/index.php url to http://localhost/yiiwebsite/.

Can anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's described in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers).

Here is some basic info:

> The application installed according to the above instructions should
>   work out of box with either an Apache HTTP server or an Nginx HTTP
>   server, on Windows, Mac OS X, or Linux running PHP 5.4 or higher. Yii
>   2.0 is also compatible with facebook's HHVM. However, there are some edge cases where HHVM behaves different than native PHP, so you have
>   to take some extra care when using HHVM.
>
> On a production server, you may want to configure your Web server so
>   that the application can be accessed via the URL
>   `http://www.example.com/index.php` instead of
>   `http://www.example.com/basic/web/index.php`. Such configuration
>   requires pointing the document root of your Web server to the
>   `basic/web` folder. You may also want to hide `index.php` from the URL, as
>   described in the Routing and URL Creation section. In this subsection,
>   you'll learn how to configure your Apache or Nginx server to achieve
>   these goals.
>
> By setting `basic/web` as the document root, you also prevent end users
>   from accessing your private application code and sensitive data files
>   that are stored in the sibling directories of `basic/web`. Denying
>   access to those other folders is a security improvement.
>
> If your application will run in a shared hosting environment where you
>   do not have permission to modify its Web server configuration, you may
>   still adjust the structure of your application for better security.

Further configuration depends on chosen web server (Nginx / Apache), which is not even mentioned in the questoin. But both options are covered in official docs by the given link.

For shared hosting environment there is [special section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html) too.

And by the way this was asked before many times here on SO, just do a better research.